# Wordpress custom post type category listings not showing up

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, custom-post-type

I have set up a custom post type called products:

```
add_action( 'init', 'register_cpt_product' );

function register_cpt_product() 
{
    $labels = array(
        'name' => _x( 'products', 'products' ),
        'singular_name' => _x( 'product', 'products' ),
        'add_new' => _x( 'Add New', 'products' ),
        'add_new_item' => _x( 'Add New product', 'products' ),
        'edit_item' => _x( 'Edit product', 'products' ),
        'new_item' => _x( 'New product', 'products' ),
        'view_item' => _x( 'View product', 'products' ),
        'search_items' => _x( 'Search products', 'products' ),
        'not_found' => _x( 'No products found', 'products' ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => _x( 'No products found in Trash', 'products' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => _x( 'Parent product:', 'products' ),
        'menu_name' => _x( 'products', 'products' ),
    );
    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'thumbnail' ),
        'taxonomies' => array( 'category', 'post_tag' ),
        'public' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_in_menu' => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'can_export' => true,
        'rewrite' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post'
    );

    register_post_type( 'products', $args );
}
```

The products work with [my custom archive page](http://drysuits.dannycheeseman.me/products/).  But not with the categories; I just get a "not found".

http://drysuits.dannycheeseman.me/category/lights/

I have deleted .htaccess and resaved the permalinks.. (/%postname%/)

Any ideas as to why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use for custom taxonomy category list plugin for display category sidebar. or

You can use the `wp_list_categories` function to create a list in your sidebar, [the Codex article](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories#Display_Terms_in_a_custom_taxonomy) has a code example, but something like this should work:

```
<ul>
<?php wp_list_categories('taxonomy=products'); ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your input.. I am talking about the actual products in that category.. http://drysuits.dannycheeseman.me/category/lights/ there should be products listed.. There is not.. ??

Comment: i see that but sidebar category is a blog category not your products taxonomy category so please get taxonomy product category and taxonomy product list.

Comment: $args = array(
 'type'                     => 'product',
 'child_of'                 => 0,
 'parent'                   => '',
 'orderby'                  => 'name',
 'order'                    => 'ASC',
 'hide_empty'               => 1,
 'hierarchical'             => 1,
 'exclude'                  => '',
 'include'                  => '',
 'number'                   => '',
 'taxonomy'                 => 'category',
 'pad_counts'               => false );
$categories = get_categories($args);

Comment: genearte own custom post category using: fist you add one post in light and see the light category you use default blog category functionality. http://www.deluxeblogtips.com/2010/07/custom-post-type-with-categories-post.html